# Building on macOS with a prefix

Tags: osx, build

When I pull 25.1 down from FTP and configure using the following (extrapolated from [this run](https://travis-ci.org/vermiculus/emake.el-example/jobs/497686582#L130)):

```
curl -o "/tmp/emacs-25.1.tar.xz" "https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/emacs-25.1.tar.xz"
tar xf "/tmp/emacs-25.1.tar.xz" -C /tmp
cd /tmp/emacs-25.1
./configure --prefix=/Users/travis/emacs --with-ns --with-modules
make
sudo make install
```

it's actually seems to be configuring without the `--prefix`.  I'm basing that assumption off

1. There's nothing in the prefix dir after `make install`.
2. There's still stuff in `/tmp/emacs-25.1/`.

So, I think to myself, 'no big deal, I'll just copy `/tmp/emacs-25.1/` to `/home/travis/emacs` myself' – but [that's a no-go](https://travis-ci.org/vermiculus/emake.el-example/jobs/497691575#L143).

Copying everything back into `/tmp/emacs-25.1` [does work](https://travis-ci.org/vermiculus/emake.el-example/jobs/497693193#L132), but it's bordering on too hacky.

Why isn't `--prefix` being respected?  Do I misunderstand its purpose?  This seems to apply across the board for macOS builds regardless of version.

Answer (score 2):

On macOS, Emacs builds itself a self-contained application bundle by default. You can find it in the build tree via the output at the end of the `./configure` step.

```
You must run "make install" in order to test the built application.
The installed application will go to nextstep/Emacs.app and can be
run or moved from there.
The application will be fully self-contained.
```

You can then copy/move this bundle to `~/Applications` or `/Applications`. To override this behavior, take a look at `./configure --help`, under "Optional Features:"

```
Optional Features:
  --disable-option-checking  ignore unrecognized --enable/--with options
  --disable-FEATURE       do not include FEATURE (same as --enable-FEATURE=no)
  --enable-FEATURE[=ARG]  include FEATURE [ARG=yes]
  --enable-silent-rules   less verbose build output (undo: "make V=1")
  --disable-silent-rules  verbose build output (undo: "make V=0")
  --disable-ns-self-contained
                          disable self contained build under NeXTstep
```

`--disable-ns-self-contained` will give you a more traditional layout, respecting `--prefix`.